# Imitate behaviour of TextImageRelation in custom button

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I want to create a custom button in WinForms using GDI+. I am inheriting from `System.Windows.Forms.Button` and overriding the `OnPaint` method to render a custom button.

I want to render images and text just how the original `System.Windows.Forms.Button` does, including the ability to respect the `TextImageRelation`, `TextAlign` and `ImageAlign` properties.

How would I go about this? Is there already a built-in way to do this?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to do something different?

Comment: @StackOverflowNaziHater How do you mean that? I want to change the appearance of the button, but keep the behaviour of any image or text rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want, you may need to re-create the logic to draw button.

You would need to use the Graphics methods to perform the task.

```
public class FirstControl : Control{  
   public FirstControl() {}  
   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {  
      // Call the OnPaint method of the base class.  
      base.OnPaint(e);  
      // Call methods of the System.Drawing.Graphics object.  
      e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), ClientRectangle);  
   }   
}
```

You may need to measure a string:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx

There is this also:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonrenderer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I know how to draw strings and images. I was just hoping that I wouldn't have to recreate every aspect of the logic.

Comment: When manually rendering, [StringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.StringFormat);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) becomes mandatory for Alignment (general and Culture specific), disposition and quality. Also, for text, [Graphics.TextRenderingHint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.textrenderinghint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @Jimi StringFormat is indeed very handy. Is there also any way to include `TextImageRelation` and `ImageAlign` in the rendering, because it also affects text rendering (positioning)?

Comment: @Jonas Kohl  Using the provided `ButtonRenderer` class (which will use TextRenderer instead of Graphics.DrawString), you have all the options already there. See the [TextFormatFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `ButtonRenderer` [DrawButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12x6t4ae(v=vs.110).aspx). You just need to override (new) TextImageRelation and retrieve its value for the rendering disposition.

Comment: @Jimi The problem with `ButtonRenderer` is that it renders a button that looks just like the default one, defeating the whole purpose of rendering my own button. I want to customise the whole appearance of the button. Is there any way `ButtonRenderer` can only draw the text and image, but not the background?

Comment: Sounds like you will need to re-create everything. Which will take a lot of time. Been a while but If I remember correctly, TextRenderer class is slower. Also It might be cheaper to find some commercial controls instead...

Comment: Another Idea, get the source for ButtonRenderer and change the pieces you need to.